# Random Black Screen Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

So after upgrading to Windows 10, every now and then I get a random black screen. I have two monitors on two different graphics boards so I know this is a software problem, and additionally if I click where the taskbar should be it appears on top of the blackness and I can click start (which I have set to open fullscreen) and reboot the PC. This is the only thing that lets me continue to use the PC. Ctrl+Alt+Delete brings up the screen, but clicking task manager does not let me see the window that is at that point open. I can hover over buttons, and I see the names of the buttons after hovering, and am able to click them, but not able to see them. Please help, thank you for reading.